# How to map a virtual host to a container in docker?

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, lamp

I am trying to setup a LEMP local development environment using Docker. Following is my docker-composer.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  apache:
    build:
      context: ./docker/apache-php7
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: foo/apache-php7
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
     - localnet
  node:
    build:
      context: ./docker/node
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: foo/node
    volumes:
     - .:/var/www/html
    networks:
     - localnet
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "root"
      MYSQL_USER: "root"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "root"
    volumes:
     - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
     - localnet
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    volumes:
     - redisdata:/data
    networks:
     - localnet
networks:
  localnet:
    driver: "bridge"
volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: "local"
  redisdata:
    driver: "local"
```

I can access the site by going to http://localhost. Instead of accessing the project using http://localhost, I am trying to map it to http://foo.dev but for the life of me I just can't figure out how I can achieve that? One example I have seen is [this](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) but it's using a different image and it is also using nginx.

Comment: @johnharris85 It might sound lazy but I am at a loss as to where to even begin. Tried official Docs, Google but I guess I am not asking the right questions so don't know where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that the foo/apache-php7 image is forked from nimmis/apache-php7, which is based on Ubuntu 16.04, so by default your Apache will answer the same way to HTTP requests, irrespective of host name.
So, the only thing you need to do is to set up A/AAAA records in the foo.dev DNS zone pointing at your server.

It looks like the zone needs some attention in any case:

```
% host foo.dev
foo.dev has address 127.0.53.53
foo.dev mail is handled by 10 your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.dev.
```

The address record points to a localhost address, which won't work until you're actually on the same host. You'll need a globally routed IP address there.

Comment: Yes it is forked from nimmis/apache-php7 image. I am a little confused on why I need to setup A/AAAA records for setting up a dev environment just for my computer. An example of what I currently do is:

1. Run a vagrant box
2. Set an IP address (e.g. 192.168.2.19)
3. On my /etc/hosts add the following:

192.168.2.19 foo.dev

Now when I navigate to foo.dev, it runs off the local virtual box instance. But with Docker I just can't seem to figure it out. And unless I have completely missed it given my noobiness with Docker, I don't your answers helps?

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do was simply add the ServerName directive in the apache conf file for the site in question. In my case, it was the 000-default.conf. I didn't even need to update the hosts file as  I am marking Gerd's answer as the answer as that is what directed me to this:

```
ServerName foo.dev
```

I then updated my hosts file with the following:

```
127.0.0.1 foo.dev www.foo.dev
```